# Floating left on absolutely positioned elements

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to achive an effect where severeal absolutely positioned elements would behave as they were being floated to the left. I'm trying to avoid using classes or nth-child selectors because the number of divs being absolutely positioned is dynamic.

So the div width is 800px and I'd like to have all divs floated to the left, but now they are stacked over eachother and I don't know how to make div 1 be left: 0, div 2 left:800, div 3 left: 1600 and so on without using classes or nth-child selectors. Is this possible using jQuery or maybe even css?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this question with jquery? It doesn't seem to apply?

Comment: Well I figure it isn't likely that there is an all-css solution and if javascript is required I'd really like it written in jQuery as I'm better with that then regular javascript. But if you feel that that's irrelevant I'll remove the jQuery tag.

Comment: Why do you want achieve the effect of floating elements, but not float them?

Comment: @user1023552 you'll need jquery, css doesn't support maths yet...

Comment: Because I need them absolutely positioned.

Comment: @user1023552 i'll keep jquery or javascript tag... seems impossible to achieve without it

Comment: just edited this jsfiddle, maybe it'll help you.. http://jsfiddle.net/FG8ef/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways....

**jQuery:**

```
$("div").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("left", 800*index);
});
```

You can position your divs relative and then float them.

But you will have to have a wrapper with the width off all divs,  in jQuery:

```
$("#wrapper").width( $("div").length * 800 );
```

---

Can you please tell more about your structure (DOM, css, etc).

This helps to make the best solution for your needs...

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! Sorry for being unclear with the structure, I'll keep that in mind til' next time.